# What does the skiplistnode variable "span" mean in redis.h?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, redis, skip-lists

In `redis.h`, the skipnode is defined as below:

```
typedef struct zskiplistNode {
    robj *obj;
    double score;
    struct zskiplistNode *backward;
    struct zskiplistLevel {
        struct zskiplistNode *forward;
        unsigned int span;
    } level[];
} zskiplistNode;
```

What does the var `span` mean? What does this var store?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`span` at a particular node stores the number of nodes between the current node and node->forward at the current level. `span` is used to calculate the 1-based rank of element in the skip list.

For example, consider the following skip list :
[image: A Skip List]

Consider the head node. The span at all levels will be 1.

Consider node 1. At level 0, the span is 1, because you will *span* 1 element if you follow the forward pointer. At level 1, span is 2 because you will *span* 2 elements (node 2 and node 3) if you follow the forward pointer.

Take a look at the [function zslGetRank in t_zet.c](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/t_zset.c#L320). You can see how the rank is calculated from the value of span at each level.

Comment: your anwer is great~~~ thank you very much~~~ But i reckon that skiplist can be replaced by red-black tree or splay-tree which maybe have a more excellent performance.

Comment: No, it cannot. A skip list offers one interesting property which RB-trees or splay trees do not have. It can find the nth item at log(n) cost. Used by ZRANGE for instance.

Comment: I think  splay tree also can find the n-th item at log(n) cost with an extra element in the node. but splay spend more times to write and read  the main memory which is not so convenient for redis,just as i think.