# ZREVRANK 'fair' ranking in REDIS

Tags: redis

When I have a sorted set with scores, I'd like to have the right rank even when multiple items have the same score.

For instance, when there are 5 items with scores: 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, I'd like to have those three central items to have the same rank (1), while the highest score gets rank 0 (with ZREVRANGE), and the lowest gets rank 4.

I see that it's possible to query the amount of keys with the same score somewhat efficiently O(log(N)), but it looks like if I want to have the scores as I want them, I'd have to use zscan, which is O(N).

Edit: add complete example based on the accepted solution

Our dataset is a sorted set with scores. For example: a has score 1, b, c and d have score 2, and e has score 3:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd aset 1 a
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd aset 2 b
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd aset 2 c
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd aset 2 d
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd aset 3 e
(integer) 1
```

[ZREVRANK](https://redis.io/commands/zrevrank) works for those items with a unique score:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zrevrank aset a
(integer) 4
127.0.0.1:6379> zrevrank aset e
(integer) 0
```

But it fails for those items with the same score:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zrevrank aset b
(integer) 3
127.0.0.1:6379> zrevrank aset c
(integer) 2
127.0.0.1:6379> zrevrank aset d
(integer) 1
```

To solve that, first get the score with [ZSCORE](https://redis.io/commands/zscore):

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zscore aset c
"2"
```

The other items have the same score, of course:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zscore aset b
"2"
127.0.0.1:6379> zscore aset d
"2"
```

To get their rank, just use [ZCOUNT](https://redis.io/commands/zcount) with the score:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zcount aset (2 +inf
(integer) 1
```

This also works for those items that have a unique score:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zcount aset (1 +inf
(integer) 4
127.0.0.1:6379> zcount aset (3 +inf
(integer) 0
```

Writing this as an atomic lua script is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: @Kevin Christopher Hery's answer is great. Also check a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52152217/how-to-get-same-rank-for-same-scores-in-redis-zrank)

Comment: holy effing shit your answer is the diamond in the sand im desparately trying to find! you saved me from being fired dude!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a given item with score `x`, you can determine its rank in O(log(N)) time with `ZCOUNT (X +inf`.

Exactly how you make use of that will depend on the details of your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

[ZREVRANGEBYLEX](https://redis.io/commands/zrevrangebylex) could be used in this case. The time complexity in this case would be O(log(N)+M) with N being the number of elements in the sorted set and M the number of elements being returned. Please look at [ZRANGEBYLEX](https://redis.io/commands/zrangebylex) for syntax.

Lex family of sorted set commands allow you to specify lexicographical ordering for keys with same values.