# Retrieving items by rank from a redis sorted set (and handling items that can share ranks)

Tags: redis

I can query a redis sorted set by score (`zrangebyscore`), by values (`zrange`), by lexicographical ordering (`zrangebylex`) etc.

But what's the best pattern to use if I wanted to retrieve the top 10 ranked items from a redis sorted set?

For me, this isn't tantamount to just retrieving the top 10 items from the sorted set (i.e. `zrevrange set_name 0 10`). Why? Because in many real-world scenarios, when certain items have the same score, they are appropriately given a shared rank. So there could be a top 10 list with 11 members (for example).

Is it possible to query for ranks in a redis sorted set in this manner?

My other option is to retrieve the entire set and do the counting outside of redis. I believe this could be suboptimal for large sets re-ranked frequently.

In case it matters, I use redis in a Python project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another sorted set to rank the scores, so that you can get the top N scores. With the returned score range, you can use `ZRANGEBYSCORE` to get the member list.

#### ADD

```
ZADD members 0 a 1 b 1 c 2 d 2 e 3 f

ZADD scores 0 0 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3
```

#### SEARCH

Get members with top 3 scores.

```
ZREVRANGE scores 0 2

// it returns '3, 2, 1' so the score range is [1, 2]

ZRANGEBYSCORE members 1 3

// you can get the result: b, c, d, e, f
```

I leave the *DELETE* part as an exercise :)

Also check [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52152217/how-to-get-same-rank-for-same-scores-in-redis-zrank).