# How to implement Competition leaderboard using redis sorted set

Tags: java, redis, leaderboard, sortedset

I'm using Redis sorted set to maintain the leaderboard of my game. I have a scenario where I need to maintain the same rank of the users who have the same score as the Competition leaderboard. Eg.

```
| member | score | rank |
— — — — — — — — — — —
| member_1 | 50 | 1 |
| member_2 | 50 | 1 |
| member_3 | 30 | 3 |
| member_4 | 30 | 3 |
| member_5 | 10 | 5 |
```

As of now, I'm using default implementation of Redis sorted set which returns the ranking lexicographically.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd test-leaderboard 9 user1
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd test-leaderboard 5 user2
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd test-leaderboard 5 user3
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd test-leaderboard 3 user4
(integer) 1
```

If I query for user2 and user3 rank, I get a different result

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zrank test-leaderboard user2
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zrank test-leaderboard user3
(integer) 2
```

I checked Redis documentation, there is no such feature to do so. So I want to know what I have to do or what is the best way to implement this functionality.

**Note:** I have 10K records in SET and I need to maintain it at runtime and I'm using Java programming language.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get same rank for same scores in Redis' ZRANK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52152217/how-to-get-same-rank-for-same-scores-in-redis-zrank)

Comment: My question is a bit different because I'm trying to do it at run time. And also I don't get the solution of the above link because it's using Lua script.

Answer (score 1):

Sorted sets are sorted first by score, then lexicographically, that's why you get a different rank for `user2` and `user3`.

You can combine `ZSCORE`, `ZRANGEBYSCORE` and `ZRANK` to normalize this. Basically, you get the score for `user3`, then get the first user lexicographically in a tie, and get the rank for that user.

```
> ZSCORE test-leaderboard user3
"5"
> ZRANGEBYSCORE test-leaderboard 5 5 LIMIT 0 1
1) "user2"
> ZRANK test-leaderboard user2
(integer) 1
```

This gives you a rank, with ties ranked the same, but leaving gaps for ranking.

```
user4 => 0
user2 => 1
user3 => 1
user1 => 3
```

If you want your ranks without gaps, you can either maintain the leaderboard with the list of users at a given score per entry (`ZADD test-leaderboard 5 "user2,user3"`), or maintain a separated sorted set with only unique scores. I would go with the second one for efficiency.

Adding a new player `[O(log(N))]`:

```
ZADD test-leaderboard 5 user2
ZADD test-ranks 5 5
```

Delete a player `[O(log(N))]`:

```
> ZSCORE test-leaderboard user2
"5"
> ZREM test-leaderboard user2
(integer) 1
> ZRANGEBYSCORE test-leaderboard 5 5 LIMIT 0 1
1) "anotherUser" or (empty list or set)
if(empty set)
> ZREM test-ranks 5
```

Update a player score `[O(log(N))]`:

```
> ZSCORE test-leaderboard user2
"5"
> ZADD test-leaderboard 10 user2
(integer) 1
> ZADD test-ranks 10 10
(integer) 1
> ZRANGEBYSCORE test-leaderboard 5 5 LIMIT 0 1
1) "anotherUser" or (empty list or set)
if(empty set)
> ZREM test-ranks 5
```

Get the rank of a player `[O(log(N))]`:

```
> ZSCORE test-leaderboard user2
"5"
> ZRANK test-ranks 5
(integer) 1
```

A couple of notes:

**Use `ZREVXXX` commands if higher score is top rank**.

`ZRANK` ranks the lowest score first, use `ZREVRANK` if you want the highest score ranked first. See [`ZREVRANK`](https://redis.io/commands/zrevrank) and [`ZREVRANGEBYSCORE`](https://redis.io/commands/zrevrangebyscore).

**Use Lua scripts**

With [Lua scripts](https://redis.io/commands/eval), you can make your operations atomic and perform them faster.

Here an example. Instead of

```
> ZSCORE test-leaderboard user2
"5"
> ZRANK test-ranks 5
(integer) 1
```

Use the script:

```
local score = redis.call('ZSCORE', KEYS[1], ARGV[1])
return redis.call('ZRANK', KEYS[2], score)
```

Use as:

```
> EVAL "local score = redis.call('ZSCORE', KEYS[1], ARGV[1]) \n return redis.call('ZRANK', KEYS[2], score)" 2 test-leaderboard test-ranks user2
(integer) 1
```